# how to specify maven compiler plugin order

Tags: java, maven, kotlin

I'm working on a mixed java and kotlin project by using maven.

The problem I'm facing right now is, `maven-compiler-plugin` runs before compiling `kotlin-maven-plugin`.

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) @annotation --- 
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 11 source files to /Users/hannes/workspace/tikxml/annotation/target/classes 
[INFO] --- kotlin-maven-plugin:1.0.0-beta-4583:compile (compile) @ annotation 
[INFO] Kotlin Compiler version 1.0.0-beta-4583
```

In my java source code I'm referencing classes written in kotlin. But javac runs before kotlinc. Hence, maven interrupts with compiler errors.

My pom (parent pom, I use submodules) looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
        <version>7</version>
    </parent>

    ...

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>annotation</module>
        <module>processor</module>
    </modules>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.0.0-beta-4583</kotlin.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>


        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/main/java</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <source>src/test/java</source>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What if you add the `maven-compiler-plugin` plugin element just after the `kotlin-maven-plugin`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Kotlin documentation on [Using Maven](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html) suggests explicitly binding the `kotlin-maven-plugin` execution to the `process-sources` phase.  Since `maven-compiler-plugin` is bound to the `compile` phase, binding `kotlin-maven-plugin` to the `process-sources` phase makes it run first.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals> <goal>compile</goal> </goals>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
            <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 6):

Although it's more verbose, you can compile both Java and Kotlin sources in the `compile` phase with the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>kotlin-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>kotlin-test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>default-testCompile</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>java-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>java-test-compile</id>
            <phase>test-compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Normally, plugins are executed in the order they are declared in the POM, but the executions of `default-compile` and `default-testCompile` are special because they're built-in, so they always go first.  The above configuration gets around that by disabling the default compile executions, and declaring `maven-compiler-plugin` with new compilation executions after the `kotlin-maven-plugin`.  In this way, you can get all compilation to properly occur during the `compile` phase of the build lifecycle.

Comment: Important note for those, who use **Tiles Maven Plugin**. It [changes execution IDs](https://github.com/repaint-io/maven-tiles#execution-ids) inside the tile to reflect tile GAV coordinates. So in order for `maven-compiler-plugin` executions override to work `<configuration tiles-keep-id="true" />` tags should be added to the `default-compile` and `default-testCompile` executions to preserve specified IDs.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but effective solution would be to change the two phases (the `<phase>` element) applied to the executions of the Kotlin Maven Plugin, from `compile` to `process-sources` and from `test-compile` to `process-test-sources`.

You want the Kotlin part to be executed before the Java one. Maven by default will invoke the Maven Compiler Plugin as part of the `compile` phase for source code, and `test-compile` for test code. Moving the Kotlin part to their previous phases would then make the flow as you wished.

If you wanted the opposite (first Java then Kotlin), then you could have moved the Kotlin part to the next phases (as an example: from `compile` to `process-classes` and from `test-compile` to `process-test-classes`).

For further details about Maven phases, check the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

Answer (score 1):

In case you are open to using a different build system, dependent projects are easy to set up with [Kobalt](http://beust.com/kobalt):

```
val p1 = javaProject { ... }

val p2 = kotlinProject(p1) { ... }
```

This makes project `p2` depend on `p1`. You can also mix Java and Kotlin projects.