# error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3 when compiling Java code with Kotlin

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, kotlin

I'm using Maven and the `kotlin-maven-plugin` to compile code.

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirs>
                    <source>src/main/kotlin</source>
                    <source>src/main/resources</source>
                    <source>target/generated-sources/jooq-h2</source>
                </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>

        <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirs>
                    <source>src/test/kotlin</source>
                </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The `target/generated-sources/jooq-h2` directory contains Java source files. I'm following the [Kotlin manual](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources) and other [people's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34438270/521799) by putting the Kotlin complation in `<phase>process-sources</phase>` rather than `<phase>compile</phase>`. I'm (probably wrongly?) assuming that the Kotlin compiler also takes care of compiling those Java files for me.

However, on some servers (e.g. Jenkins CI), I got strange compilation error messages, such as:

```
[ERROR] /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jooq-build/workspace/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-kotlin-example/target/generated-sources/jooq-h2/org/jooq/example/db/h2/tables/Author.java:[35,37] 
        error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

Why is that?

Comment: What is the difference with those questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6513479/1743880, or http://stackoverflow.com/q/7597950/1743880, or http://stackoverflow.com/q/16662830/1743880?

Comment: @Tunaki: No Kotlin. Specifically, I (wrongly) assumed that the Kotlin compiler would also compile Java classes for me.

Comment: @LukasEder Kotlin only uses the Java classes to generate stubs for Kotlin to compile against, then Kotlin is compiled before Java, later SOMETHING ELSE compiles Java.

Answer (score 5):

I've noticed that in this particular Kotlin project, the Java compiler and specifically the Java version were not specified. This resulted in some machine default having been chosen, which is Java 1.8 for my local machine, but Java 1.3 on the Jenkins CI server. Adding an explicit reference to the `maven-compiler-plugin` solved the issue for me:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```